# Memory leak of the substring method in java

Tags: java, string

I am searching about the memory leak that was caused by subString() method in java. I have read few articles in the internet and got some knowledge but I was ended up with a little confusion. One article has mentioned "substring method inside String class, calls String (int offset, int count, char value []) constructor to create new String object. What is interesting here is, value[], which is the same character array used to represent original string". This is clear to me.

It also mentioned "If the original string is very long, and has array of size 1GB, no matter how small a substring is, it will hold 1GB array.  **This will also stop original string to be garbage collected, in case if doesn't have any live reference**".

**The link to the article is here** {http://javarevisited.blogspot.sg/2011/10/how-substring-in-java-works.html}

I cannot understand this. Please anybody explain me how does it stop the original string to be garbage collected if it does't have any live reference?

According to my little understanding, in java any object which doesn't have direct or indirect reference will be eligible for garbage collector to collect. If subString method uses the same character array used to represent original string how can the original String stay without being garbage collected ?

Likewise I want to know does the memory leak is caused due to use the same character array used to represent original string because the new string {String returned by subString method} would be very little compared with the original String or since the original string is still staying without being garbage collected?

Please anybody help me to clarify this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you allocate anything in Java, and in this case a `String`, it stays in memory for as long as you still have a way of accessing it. If you write

```
String s = "blah";
```

then `s` is a *reference* to that `String`. As long as there's at least one reference to the `String`, then the JVM knows it needs to be kept around in memory. Once there are no more references, then the JVM can clean it up and reclaim the memory when it needs to.

If you write

```
String s = "myverylongstring...somemore...someotherstuff";
```

then you've used up quite a lot of memory. Internally, this will be represented as a `char[]` containing all of the characters of your `String`, with some extra gubbins round the edge to allow you to access it using the `String` API.

Now, what happens if you then write

```
s = s.substring(20,30);
```

so that `s` is now a reference just to part of the original `String`? There are two ways the JVM might deal with it. One is to keep the whole `char[]` in memory, but just change which bit of the `char[]` it's prepared to let you get access to. The other is to copy the relevant bit of the `char[]` into a new array, and then get rid of all references to the old one.

The first approach is quick, because it doesn't need any copying. But if you now only want a small bit of your huge `String`, then the whole of the big `String` can't ever be fully cleaned up because the whole of its `char[]` is still in memory being used. The fact that only *part* of it is being used means that *none* of its memory can be reclaimed.

The second approach is slower, because it needs a copy operation. But it does mean that the previous `String` can be cleaned up in its entirety, because the old `char[]` isn't being used any more.

Java *used* to follow the first approach, but in recent times (Java 7 onwards) it's switched to using the second. So memory leaks used to be a problem with the `substring()` call, but aren't any longer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply sir! According to the first way you mentioned does it means it will take the original string in to a char[] array and picked up the portion of the bits from the char[] array and we can access to that portion of the bits since we used subString but the rest of the bits in the array are still available and garbage collector cannot collect it since we use portion of the bits in char[] array?

Comment: @Dilan A `String` is represented by a `char[]` and two other values: one telling you where in the array the `String` starts, and the other telling you how long it is. So in order to create a substring, we can create a new `String` that has a reference to the same `char[]`, but with a different start point and length. The point is that by copying the *reference* to the `char[]`, we avoid copying but the garbage collector now needs to keep the whole `char[]` even though we're only using a bit of it.

Answer (score 1):

The wording is a bit sloppy. The original String instance will be garbage-collected. But its internal array of characters won't, since it's still referenced by the substring.

In an extreme case, you could thus have a String instance of length 1 referencing a 1GB array.

Before:

```
s1 ---------> object --> char[] (1GB large)
               - offset
               - count
```

substring is called:

```
s1 ---------> object --> char[] (1GB large)
              - offset  ^
              - count   |
                        |
substring --> object ---/
              - offset
              - count
```

s1 goes out of scope: object can be garbage collected

```
                         char[] (1GB large)
                        ^
                        |
substring --> object ---/
              - offset
              - count
```

Comment: This is no longer true. This behavior was changed in Java 7. The `String` constructor is now copying the internal array, so the internal array of the original will be garbage-collected.

Comment: I know that. But the question was about explaining the memory leak that existed before, when this was still how substring was implemented.

Answer (score 0):

In accord with @chiastic-security answer, also find this reference for detailed explanation on Java 8 treatment for memory leak prevention

http://mrgyani.com/java-interview/memory-leak-problem-in-java-substring/